# format Rss feed published Date

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use the Ionic Framework to create an RSS feed with Google's Feed API (https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/reference). Rss Feed works but Published Date is not formatted. For date formatting, I use the `angular-locale_de-de.js`, so that I can use the German time format.

call of the published date:

```
<span>{{entry.publishedDate}}</span>
```

This is shown:

```
Tue, 07 Jul 2015 23:22:19 -0700
```

I would like the date to be displayed as follows:

```
Dienstag, 7. Juli 2015, 23:22
```

How can I call the date after formatting?

Answer (score 0):

For the language problem (as being English instead of German) The reference to angular-locale_de-de.js must be broken. Otherwise you at least get the German language in the formatting. (here I assume publishedDate is actually a date, not a string)

For the formatting, either you can create a new AngularJS filter, or just combine existing filters. Here are two ways to achieve what you want

```
  <span ng-controller="Ctrl1">

{{entry.PublishedDate |date : "fullDate" }}
{{entry.PublishedDate |date : "shortTime" }}

  <br/>

{{(entry.PublishedDate |date : "fullDate")+" "+(entry.PublishedDate |date : "shortTime") }}
  </span>
```

which I have put into this Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/7hcJeq4auYvPZK1diuVR?p=preview

and creates date and time in German

Comment: But that takes the system date, not the date of publication of the article? The time is also system time. But I wanted to show the publication time

Comment: ok, I was providing just an example. I updated the above code to use your variable. I guess you get those from some RESTful service

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The code assumes still the current date of the system:

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $element, $http) {
 $scope.entry.PublishedDate = new Date();
  })

<blink>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    {{(entry.PublishedDate |date : "fullDate")+" "+(entry.PublishedDate |date : "shortTime") }}
   </div>
</blink>

Comment: So you want to get it from some DB? Your question was about formatting only, so I thought you know how to fetch the values from DB and put in your page

Comment: Yes, the Date `PublishedDate` is on a rss server.